# How to build my own mesos framework?

Tags: frameworks, mesos, mesosphere

I am sorry about this question but I am new to mesos and I am curious to know, how should I go about building my own mesos framework. Any step by step guide or good resources would be much helpful.

Comment: I found this recently, might be useful: http://container-solutions.com/mesos-framework-overview/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with docs. There is whole [Developing Mesos Frameworks](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/) section about developing own framework.

New approach in developing frameworks is to use HTTP API which provides more features (like reverse offers) so definietely read about [scheduler](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/scheduler-http-api/) and [executor](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/executor-http-api/) HTTP API.

Of course taking a look on other frameworks will be good point to start. Depending on your need this could be [Aurora](http://aurora.apache.org/), [Fenzo](https://github.com/Netflix/Fenzo), [Marathon](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon). Whole list is [here](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/frameworks/)

There is a framework to build Mesos frameworks called [Mesos-starter](https://github.com/ContainerSolutions/mesos-starter).
If you want to use native API there are official bindings for C++, Python and Java but there are unofficial bindings for other languages like [Go](https://github.com/mesos/mesos-go), [JS](https://github.com/tobilg/mesos-framework) or [Clojure](https://github.com/dgrnbrg/clj-mesos).

Comment: And JS as well: https://github.com/tobilg/mesos-framework

Comment: @Tobi: Thanks for the resources